# htacces rewriteRule extensive url's

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

I moved a multi store Magento website to an other domain.
For redirecting all the page, I used a htaccess file.

The old domains are:

```
www.olddomain.nl -> www.newdomain.nl
www.olddomain.nl/categoryone -> www.newdomaincategoryone.nl
www.olddomain.nl/categorytwo -> www.newdomaincategorytwo.nl
www.olddomain.nl/categorythree -> www.newdomaincategorythree.nl
```

This is working, but when the path is more extensively, it does not work anymore.

For example:

```
 http://www.oldomain.nl/categoryone/subcategory/product to
 http://www.newdomaincategoryone.nl/subcategory/product
```

The htaccess code is:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /

         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*olddomain\.nl [OR]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.nl  [NC]

     RewriteRule ^categoryone/?$(.*)  http://www.newdomaincategoryone.nl/$1 [R=301,NC]
     RewriteRule ^categorytwo/?$(.*)  http://www.newdomaincategorytwo.nl/$1 [R=301,NC]
     RewriteRule ^/?$(.*) http://www.newdomain.nl [R=301,NC]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rules and regex are incorrect.

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.nl$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^categoryone(/.*)?$ http://www.newdomaincategoryone.nl$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.nl$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^categorytwo(/.*)?$ http://www.newdomaincategorytwo.nl$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.nl$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.newdomain.nl [R=301,NC,L]
```